# Build AOSP(Android Open Source Project) on MAC

Tags: android, macos

When I execute make, I got an error:

> Yacc: libmcldScript <= frameworks/compile/mclinker/lib/Script/ScriptParser.yy
>   prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison -d  -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libmcldScript_intermediates/ScriptParser.cpp frameworks/compile/mclinker/lib/Script/ScriptParser.yy
>   Import includes file: out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libmcldScript_intermediates/import_includes
>   frameworks/compile/mclinker/lib/Script/ScriptParser.yy:28.1-5: invalid directive: `%code'
>   frameworks/compile/mclinker/lib/Script/ScriptParser.yy:28.7-14: syntax error, unexpected identifier
>   make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libmcldScript_intermediates/ScriptParser.cpp] Error 1
>   make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   Lex: libmcldScript <= frameworks/compile/mclinker/lib/Script/ScriptScanner.ll

Environment:

```
Mac SDK : 10.13
Mac OS  : 10.13.1
Android : 6.0.1
XCode   : 9.2
make    : 3.81
```

Comment: Try `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/flex/bin:/usr/local/opt/bison/bin:$PATH` before you execute make

Comment: Are you working on an android project in `Xcode`?

Comment: @Marka  No, I'm just compiling Android source in the terminal

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov I tried it, throw the same error